# How to compare integers on fish shell?

Tags: fish

There isn't much documentation on fish. I need to know if

```
    date '+%k' is greater than 8
```

How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I'd agree "there isn't much documentation on fish". Have you seen http://fishshell.com/? Most of which is available via the `man` command. If there is something you think we can that would have made it easier for you to answer your question please open an issue: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new

Answer (score 6):

`test` or `[` are the way you would do this. This is true of all shells, since these are external commands.

```
if [ (date '+%k') -ge 8 ]
    echo "It's larger!"
end
```

Comment: To be pedantic: `test` and `[` are *not* external commands in most shells (including `fish` and `bash`).  You can verify this by using the `type` builtin, which will show that both of these are also builtins.  However, most systems *do* provide `/bin/test` and `/bin/[` so these are possible to use even if the shell does not provide them.  But shells always use builtins before external commands of the same name.

Comment: Yes, `test` and `[` may also be builtins. However because they are external commands, their behavior is fixed, so they'll be common across all shells, i.e. no shell will provide a `[` builtin that breaks compatibility with `/bin/[`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `test` fish builtin, like:

```
if test (date +%k) -gt 8
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in traditional languages, but similar to other shell languages, the `if` operator in fish works on exit status of commands. Therefore an additional command `test` is used to translate logical/mathematical operations into exit status codes.

here are some examples:

```
count $argrv              # returns 0
test (count $argrv) -eq 0 # returns 0, which is evaluated as TRUE by if
test (count $argrv) -eq 1 # returns 1, which is evaluated as FALSE by if
```

here's how you check if the hour is greater then 8

```
function testIf
    if  test (date '+%k') -gt 8
        echo "yes"
    else 
        echo "no"
    end
end
```